# search recursively for couple of folders in present directory and add the found folders to a zip file

Tags: powershell, recursion, search, archive

For a given folder in Windows say `$currentDir = Get-Location` I wish to search recursively for these two folders `json` & `txt` which must be under `db_execute` folder.

Below is my powershell for the same which does not work as desired.

```
# Define the names of the folders to search for
$folderNames = "db_execute\json", "db_execute\txt"

$zipFileName = "Folders.zip"

$currentDir = Get-Location

# Create an empty zip file
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $currentDir -DestinationPath $zipFileName -CompressionLevel Optimal -Update

# Loop through each folder name
foreach ($folderName in $folderNames) {
    # Find all the subdirectories with the given name in the current directory recursively
    $subDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Directory -Recurse -Filter $folderName

    # Loop through each subdirectory
    foreach ($subDir in $subDirs) {
        # Add the subdirectory to the zip file
        Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $subDir.FullName -DestinationPath $zipFileName -CompressionLevel Optimal -Update
    }
}
```

this creates a `Folder.zip` having several files and folders, but i need it to have Just-only these two folders `db_execute_scripts\json,db_execute_scripts\txt` along with their contents.

```
$currentDir
   | -- source
          |--- repo
                 | db_execute
                       |--- txt
                       |--- json
```

Note the `db_execute` can be anywhere inside $currentDir. The above is just an example and this structure may change.

Desired

```
 Folders.zip
       |--- db_execute
                 |--- txt
                 |--- json
```

Can you please suggest what I'm doing wrong in my PowerShell?

Comment: I do not think `Get-ChildItem` will work with a `-Filter` like that. What result do you get from the command `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'db_execute\txt'`?

Comment: I'd create a temptorary copy of the folder structure you want to compress where you omit all folders and files you don't want to include. This way you can preserve the folder structure in your archive. 

Comment: @lit `PS source> Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'db_execute\txt'
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\HOME\source\db_execute'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'db_execute\txt'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\HOME\source:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand` Note: db_execute does exist in subdirectory location

Answer (score -1):

@Ashar, you can use this script to achieve your requirement

```
# Define the names of the folders to search for
$folderNames = @("json", "txt")

$zipFileName = "Folders.zip"

$currentDir = Get-Location

# Loop through each folder name
foreach ($folderName in $folderNames) {
    # Find the folder with the given name in the current directory recursively
    $folder = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Directory -Recurse -Filter $folderName

    # Check if the folder exists
    if ($folder) {
        # Add the folder and its contents to the zip file
        Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $folder.FullName -DestinationPath $zipFileName -CompressionLevel Optimal -Update
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with your original script is that it's creating an archive of the entire directory using Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $currentDir -DestinationPath $zipFileName, and then it attempts to add the individual subdirectories that match your criteria.

This approach doesn't work as expected because it creates a zip file of the entire directory first, including all its contents, and then adds the individual folders to that zip. It doesn't achieve the goal of creating a zip file that contains only the "db_execute_scripts\json" and "db_execute_scripts\txt" folders and their contents.

Comment: Are you sure you can filter on two folder names/levels at the same time? I don't believe this works as is.

Comment: @TheFreelancer Please do not add additional information as comment. Instead edit your Answer and add it there. Thanks in advance. 

Comment: @TheFreelancer answer does not work . Error `Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\HOME\source\db_execute_scripts'.
At line:11 char:15
+ ...   $folder = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Directory -Recurse -Filt ...
+                 
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\HOME\source:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\HOME\source\db_execute_scripts'.
At line:11
+ ...   $folder = Get`

Comment: @Ashar you can use the updated script. It is working fine in my environment.

Comment: @TheFreelancer i ran the command and there is no error now but no zip files are created at this location -> `PS C:\Users\HOME\source` when it should

Comment: @Ashar I hope that your data is on the same location which you have shared here. Other wise you can use Set-Location <enter you path for Source Folder>. LIke I have my source folder in Downlaods so I set-location in powershell C:\Users\thefreelancer\Downloads>

Comment: @TheFreelancer can you share the actual path for your current directory and the absolute path to `db_execute` folder ?

Comment: @Ashar my actual path for the directory is C:\Users\parveen.kumar\Downloads, where I have stored the source folder, and the zip will be created on the downloads folder only.

Comment: Does not wor. I have shared the directory structure and current directory in the original Post. can you follow the same for you r test @TheFreelancer

Answer (score -1):

@Ashar, Try this instead.

```
# Define the subfolder name for the zip
$subfolderName = "db_execute"

# Define the selection folder
$selectionFolder = "db_execute"

# Define the output zip file name
$zipFileName = "folders.zip"

# Get the current directory
$currentPath = Get-Location

# Get all subdirectories recursively
$subDirectories = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path $currentPath

# Filter subdirectories based on specific criteria, e.g., you can check for "json" and "txt" subdirectories
$jsonFolders = $subDirectories | Where-Object { $_.FullName -like "*\$selectionFolder\*" } | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "json" }
$txtFolders = $subDirectories | Where-Object { $_.FullName -like "*\$selectionFolder\*" } | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "txt" }

# Check if both "json" and "txt" subdirectories exist
if ($jsonFolders.Count -gt 0 -and $txtFolders.Count -gt 0) {
    # Create a temporary folder
    $tempDir = New-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $currentPath -ChildPath $subfolderName) -ItemType Directory -Force

    # Copy the content of the "json" and "txt" subdirectories to the temporary folder
    Copy-Item -Path $jsonFolders.FullName -Destination (Join-Path -Path $tempDir.FullName -ChildPath "json") -Recurse
    Copy-Item -Path $txtFolders.FullName -Destination (Join-Path -Path $tempDir.FullName -ChildPath "txt") -Recurse

    # Compress the temporary folder into a zip file
    Compress-Archive -Path $tempDir.FullName -DestinationPath (Join-Path -Path $currentPath -ChildPath $zipFileName) -Force

    # Clean up the temporary folder
    Remove-Item -Path $tempDir.FullName -Recurse -Force

    Write-Host "Folders have been compressed into $zipFileName with subfolder '$subfolderName'."
} else {
    Write-Host "One or both of the 'json' and 'txt' subdirectories do not exist."
}
```

Comment: getting error for `Path` line 8 here -> `Compress-Archive : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
At line:8 char:24`

Comment: i changed `Compress-Archive -Path $null -DestinationPath $zipFileName -Force` to `Compress-Archive -Path $currentDir -DestinationPath $zipFileName -Force`. The script runs alright but the zip file is not created @ `$currentDir`. I ever hard coded the absolute path for `-Path` but that too did not help.

Comment: @Ashar apologies, I made an error with the creation of the empty zip file. Try it now.

Comment: it still does not work. No zip file created. Also, my requirement is not to find any `json` or `txt` folders  but only those which are under `db_execute` folder

Comment: @Ashar

I've tested your use case and updated it. Not the most efficient thing in the world, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the creation of the $subDirs array. This code finds the directory paths that end with a value in the $folderNames array.

It does not appear that an empty .zip file needs to be created.

```
$folderNames = "db_execute\json", "db_execute\txt"
$zipFileName = "Folders.zip"
$currentDir = Get-Location

# Get a list of directories that end with one of the $folderNames
$subDirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $currentDir |
    ForEach-Object {
        foreach ($folderName in $folderNames) {
            if ($_.FullName.EndsWith($folderName)) { $_.FullName }
        }
    }

foreach ($subDir in $subDirs) {
    # Add the subdirectory to the zip file
    Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $subDir -DestinationPath $zipFileName -CompressionLevel Optimal -Update
}
```

Comment: the zip is not created

Comment: In which directory are you looking to find the `Folders.zip` file? Please describe what does happen. Have you stepped through this with a debugger?